# Why Java Integer.MIN_VALUE is -2^31 but not -2^31+1 like c++

Tags: java, c++, integer, overflow

I'm checking the Java doc, and seeing that Integer.MIN_VALUE is -2^31:

> A constant holding the minimum value an int can have, -2^31.

While in C++, the 32 bits signed integer "long" has a different MIN value:

> LONG_MIN: Minimum value for an object of type long int    -2147483647
>   (-2^31+1) or less*

I am very confused why they are different and how Java get -2^31? In Java, if an integer has 32 bits and the first bit is used for sign, -2^31+1 is more logical, isn't it?

Comment: I think, **or less** is important part here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the most significant bit in a 32 bit number is 2^31, and as this is negative in a signed integer the value is -2^31. I guess C++ uses -2^31+1 as the MIN_VALUE because this means it has the same absolute value as MAX_VALUE i.e. 2^31-1. This means an integer could store -MIN_VALUE, which is not the case in Java (which can cause some fun bugs).

Comment: k, I just figured that the MIN_VALUE is 8000000 instead of FFFFFFFF. Which means in C++, 80000000 is abandoned? What will I get if I assign 1 << 31 to a signed integer in C++?

Comment: @zeroliu what happens if you test it?

Comment: Well, it sounds like C++ uses 80000001 which, as I say has the advantage that -MAX_VALUE = MIN_VALUE. In Java -MIN_VALUE does not fit in an integer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I got -2147483648 using printf("%d", 1<<31). What I understand is that 80000000 is legal for signed integer in C++. Just in <climits>, it takes -2^31+1 as MIN because of the reason BarrySW19 mentioned. Actually, after taking a careful look at the doc, it says "-2147483647 (-2^31+1) or less*" "* the actual value depends on the particular system and library implementation"

Comment: -2^31 + 1 would be the minimum of a 32-bit integer using a sign bit notation instead of two's complement. Not that anyone would do that for decades. However, C & C++ allow such surprises.

Comment: C allows sign-magnitude or one's complement so it can't define `-2^n` as the minimum value. Instead if defines the *minimum range* for types so 2's complement implentation will have minimum value as `-2^n + 1` like normal

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ are intended to work with the native representation on machines using 1s or 2s complement or signed magnitude. With 2s complement you get a range from -2  <sup>n</sup>  through 2  <sup>n</sup> -1, about like in Java. Otherwise you lose the most negative number and gain a representation for -0.

In C++ you're only guaranteed that `n` (the number of bits)is at least 16 where Java guarantees it's exactly 32.