# Why is the minimum value for an int in java -2^31 and not -2^31-1

Tags: java, integer, primitive, primitive-types

In java I understand that an int is 32 bits in size. Java does not support unsigned values so one bit is used to hold the information on whether the int is negative or positive. So the remaining 31 bits hold the value of the number. The highest 31 bits can go is (2^31)-1 which is the highest value an in t in java can hold but why can it go all the way down to -2^31 and not -2^31-1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Java Integer.MIN\_VALUE is -2^31 but not -2^31+1 like c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26579083/why-java-integer-min-value-is-231-but-not-2311-like-c)

Comment: You can also figure it out yourself by understanding 2s-complement. And you *probably* mean `-2^31+1` since `-1` would make it even less.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't particularly have anything to do with Java, it's how all computing represents integers with 32 bits.  But to answer that question: out of 2^32 possible values, half -- 2^31 -- of those values are used to represent *nonnegative* values, *including* 0.  So there's 2^31 - 1 values to represent positive numbers, so the highest is 2^31 - 1.

The other half -- 2^31 -- are all used to represent negative numbers, so they go all the way down to -2^31.

Comment: So are you saying that 0 is stored only on the positively signed numbers, so if I input -0 it would be stored as zero and the signing bit would be set to +, which leaves an extra number for the negative side. So for every number that is negative assuming we have -2 it would be saved in binary as 01 and the 32nd bit is set to  negative and since it's negative the 1 difference is accounted for?

Comment: -2 isn't saved in binary as 01, it's actually stored as (truncated to 8 bits) 11111110, but yes.

Comment: OK, so what I am getting from your response is that, these 32 bits can represent 2^32 numbers. If you divided this into two you would get 2^31. So with these 32 bits you can represent 2^31 negative AND positive values but this would leave zero out, this means zero takes the spot of one of the positive numbers. So now my question is that for a signed integer would 1 base 10 be represented as 01 base two or 100000000000000000000000000000001 base two in the computer or something else completely. You said it would be stored as 11111110, how?

Comment: 1 is represented as 00...001.  -2 is represented as 11..110.  You can learn more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: I checked out the two's complement and it explained everything. Thank you very much